# Get best and efficient location Updates

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

In my application i want to update user location on server after certain time and change in distance. For this i created a service which is working fine but the only issue is in settings Location it shows high battery use.

Here is My Service class

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
public LocationManager locationManager;
public MyLocationListener listener;
public Location previousBestLocation = null;
PrefStore store;


Intent intent;
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    store = new PrefStore(this);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new MyLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, TWO_MINUTES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, listener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TWO_MINUTES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, listener);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks whether two providers are the same
 */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
    locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
}

public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {

            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return t;
}


public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
        Log.i("//////////", "Location changed");
        if (isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
            store.setString("Lat", loc.getLatitude() + "");
            store.setString("Long", loc.getLongitude() + "");
            loc.getLongitude();
            previousBestLocation = loc;
            if (store != null) {
                if (store.getInt(Constants.IS_APPLICATION_VISIBLE, 0) == 1) {   //App is running send update through application
                    intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
                    intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    if (store.getString(Constants.gcmToken) != null) {
                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        Log.d("", "Device_id-" + deviceId);
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("device_token", store.getString(Constants.gcmToken));
                        params.put("device_id", deviceId);
                        params.put("device_os", "android");
                        params.put("client", Constants.clientId);
                        params.put("language", store.getInt("Language", 0) + "");
                        params.put("long", loc.getLongitude() + "");
                        params.put("lat", loc.getLatitude() + "");
                        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.urlUpdateLocation, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                                try {
                                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                            }
                        });
                        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

}

What i am doing wrong?

Thanx in advance

Comment: try setting `MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE` to `0` and check if it shows high battery use

Comment: yes it is showing high battery usage